# Are Constitution changes retroactive when calculating max HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, character-advancement, hit-points

Lets say I'm a fighter that just leveled up to level 4, and decide to bring my Constitution up from 16 to 18. How many hit points do I have?

Level 1 = 10 (base) + 3 (Con mod) = 13.

Level 2 = 10 + 6 (average HP per fighter level) + 3 (Con mod) x 2 = 22

Level 3 = 10 + 6 (average) x 2 + 3 (Con mod) x 3 = 31

Level 4 = 10 + 6 (avg) x 3 + 3 (Con mod) x 3 (3 level-ups) + 4 (increased Con mod, which is now 4) x 1 = 41?

OR

Level 4 = 10 + 6 (avg) x 3 + 4 x 4 (4 times *current* Con mod) = 44?

If it's the first option, it's simply better to level Constitution up at earlier levels.

Comment: Other than it's kind of confusing, I don't know why this question is voted down.  I did not know CON increases worked this way, and have been playing a long time.  (although, I don't recall ever increasing my CON with level increases)  I thought it was a good question.

Answer (score 41):

### CON changes apply retroactively, so it doesn't matter when you increase it.

PHB 177:

> If your Constitution modifier changes, your hit point maximum changes as well, as though you had the new modifier from 1st level.

Comment: Thank you very much!
sorry if my question was confusing.