# What happens if a character's stats are lowered, reducing the number of spells they can prepare?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, ability-scores, spellcasting

What happens if a character's stats are lowered, reducing the number of spells they can prepare?

Say a level 1 cleric has a Wisdom score of 18. According to the [Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#Spellcasting-108) feature , they can prepare 5 spells (Wisdom modifier of 4 + 1 level of cleric). Now say the cleric obtains an [*ioun stone of insight*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ioun-stone) and attunes it. They now have a Wisdom modifier of 5, so they can prepare 6 spells and do so.

What happens if they then unattune to the *ioun stone*?

The rules say they can only prepare 5 spells again, but they don't indicate that the character automatically loses one prepared spell from what I can see.

Comment: Related questions: "[Are Constitution changes retroactive when calculating max HP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94302)", "[What happens at the moment I no longer meet multiclass prerequisites during gameplay?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105986)", "[Do temporary changes to your Dexterity modifier immediately affect your AC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114371)", and "[If the Cavalier fighter's Strength changes, does the number of special attacks against marked creatures change as well?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133892)".

Comment: @Medix2 I don't think it's a duplicate; that question was specifically about Wizards, while this one is about any caster that prepares their spells. It's possible that different classes might work in different ways.

Comment: @nick012000 The current answer only addresses the case of the Cleric and I'm not entirely sure this question is all that general aside from the title. Or at least, there doesn't seem to be any request for answers to assess all possible spellcasting classes where a stat determines prepared spells, barring such a request, I feel the above question is a duplicate as it addresses one such class, as the current answer here does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Cleric's [Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#Spellcasting-108) feature states about preparing spells:

> You prepare the list of cleric spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the cleric spell list. When you do so, choose a number of cleric spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your cleric level (minimum of one spell).

When preparing a spell list, you create a whole new list; you do not add or remove spells.

If you are a level 1 Cleric with 18 Wisdom, then you can prepare 5 (4 + 1) spells.

If you have the Ioun Stone, then you can prepare 6 (5 + 1) spells.

If you unattune the Ioun Stone, then you can prepare 5 (4 + 1) spells.

If you were to attune the Ioun Stone and then prepare 6 spells, then unattune the Ioun Stone, you continue having the 6 already-prepared spells. When you decide to prepare a new spell list, you will only be able to prepare 5 spells.